# How to select a specific div as a page for jQuery booklet plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

i am using jQuery booklet plugin http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/installation  to display a book on my website by default it will select all the direct child of `b-load` class as a page of the book but i just want to select a specific set of div with class name `myPages`.

i tried to modify plugin by just replacing `src.children()` by `src.children('div.myPages')` but it didn't work and it will destroy the whole structure of the web page.

So please tell me how can i do this?

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to what I understood, I think modifying `src.children()` to `src.children('div.myPages')` is sure your going to screw up your layout because the script is going to add the "paging styles" for the `div`s on the spot.

So a better easy method that I could think is to put up a separate `div` to hold the `div.mypages` and append all the `div.mypage`s onto that `div`.

Here you may see a working example http://jsfiddle.net/dNfV7/1/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find()`:

```
  children().find(".myPages")
```

It will select the specific class.